# How to play multiple sound with the Superpowered library

Tags: ios, audio, superpowered

My goal is to be able to play multiple sounds (in order to do a Drum kit), using the Superpowered API since I need very low latency.

I can't find the overall architecture in the .mm file.

For now, I have in my .mm file :

- 1 SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO* output
- 10 SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer* (players[10]), since I have 10 drums

But I can't find how to implement the rest of the .mm file, in particular the `audioProcessing` loop.

I have this currently:

```
static bool audioProcessing(Superpowered *clientdata, float **buffers, unsigned int inputChannels, unsigned int outputChannels, unsigned int numberOfSamples, unsigned int samplerate, uint64_t hostTime) {
    Superpowered *self = clientdata;

    bool overallSilence = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer *player = self->players[i];
        bool silence = !player->process(self->stereoBuffer, false, numberOfSamples);
        if (silence == false) {
            overallSilence = false;
        }
    }

    if (!overallSilence) SuperpoweredDeInterleave(self->stereoBuffer, buffers[0], buffers[1], numberOfSamples); // The stereoBuffer is ready now, let's put the finished audio into the requested buffers.

    return !overallSilence;
}
```

and when I want to play a sound:

```
- (void)playWithPlayerAtIndex:(int) index {
    SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer* player = players[index];
    player->seek(0);

    player->play(false);
}
```

But with this, I can only play hear one sound at a time.

Does anyone know the Superpowered API?

Answer (score 0):

All your players are "playing" into "self->stereoBuffer". Check the bufferAdd parameter of the player's process method. You need to "add" the output to the contents of the buffer, if at least one player did output itself into it.